# JUnit panel in eclipse

Tags: java, junit

I would like to delete the below JUnit panel in my eclipse. I am very irritated seeing it. Any idea how I can delete it? Its in my work space. Although I have pushed it all the way to the edge so I can see my code better, it is still very annoying. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Right click choose close

Comment: No. That doesn't work.

Comment: That is odd, ever gui element that attaches itself to eclipse is closable by me though I do not have that specific element, lets hope someone that does comes along.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who faces this problem in the future - Just close all the classes. Right click on the class you'd like to open, and select Open with --> Java Editor. You can make your editor default to Java by clicking on preferences --> Editors --> File associations --> *.java. Click on associated editors, and select Java editor. Choose default to make this your default editor. That finally did the trick for me :)